# Replicate a jQuery testimonial slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider

On this page here, http://themes.truethemes.net/Karma-HTML/index-jquery-1.html, at the bottom of the page there is a Testimonial slider made probably with jQuery. I'd like to make something similar but without the navigation. Something with auto height and fade effects. It also must be flexible, if I want to add an extra slide or something I just want to create a new `<div>` with a class. Could somebody point me in the right direction, or show me to a plugin? Thanks

Comment: I definitely have tried that numerous times, couldn't find anything @sv_in

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one before. It is not the flashiest, but it is easy to configure, and works with text. A lot of sliders only work with images.

http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider